# SELECT in FOR..IN loop with variable parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to use cursor data in SELECT nested to FOR..IN loop like this:

```
DECLARE 
        CURSOR c_table IS 
          SELECT a, 
                 b 
          FROM   test_table 
          WHERE  a LIKE 'XX%' 
                 AND b = 1 
          ORDER  BY a, 
                    b; 
        qty NUMBER; 
    BEGIN 
        FOR t IN c_table LOOP 
            SELECT count(*) 
            INTO   qty 
            FROM   t.a;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( qty );
        END LOOP; 
    END; 

    /
```

This code returns an error referring to nested SELECT:

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

How can data from cursor can be used in SELECT which is within FOR..IN LOOP?

Answer (score 2):

PL/SQL won't allow you to use a result column from one query or cursor as the table name in another query. You'll need to build your query dynamically:

```
DECLARE 
  CURSOR c_table IS 
    SELECT a, 
           b 
      FROM   test_table 
      WHERE  a LIKE 'XX%' 
             AND b = 1 
      ORDER  BY a, 
                b; 
  qty NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
  FOR t IN c_table LOOP 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' || t.a
      INTO qty;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( qty );
  END LOOP; 
END;
```

Best of luck.